# Entity Framework Execute Migrations on Test Server

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I need to update a test server database when deploying, and I do not find a way to do it.
We are not using automatic migrations, so we do it manually.

Can I execute it on the test server directly? Maybe a console program?

I'm using the NuGet call for local development: **Update-Database**
I know we can generate the script files, do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer to execute your migrations either through code or configuration. In code you'd do the following when the application starts:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyMigrationConfig>()
);
```

Or in your app's .config file:

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MyContext">
        <databaseInitializer
          type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[
              [MyContext], [MyMigrationConfig]
         ], EntityFramework" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj556606.aspx) - "Database Initializers" section.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Visual Studio, you can use the publish fonction to also execute a script.  Look here for more détails:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1081/building-a-web-deploy-package-from-visual-studio-2010/

If your using team fondation server, you can even automate it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2010/04/24/package-and-publish-web-sites-with-tfs-2010-build-server.aspx

Also to generate the script maybe you could use migrate.exe (it comes with ef 4.3 I think when getting the nuget package) and run it in a post build évent...